Narrow down type without duplicate strings
I want to write a generic function that uses a service. Based on this service, a set of available actions should be provided. And based on the action chosen, the required parameters should be provided.
Here is a minimal example:
class BaseService {
  declare baseAction: (base: string) => void // Must not be shown as an `action` option
}

class MyService extends BaseService {
  declare fooAction: (foo1: number, foo2: string) => void
  declare barAction: (bar: string) => void
}

class MyOtherService extends BaseService {
  declare otherAction: (other: number) => void
}

function invokeAction<TService extends BaseService>(
  action: Exclude<keyof TService, keyof BaseService> & string,
  ...args: Parameters<Extract<TService[typeof action], (...args: any) => any>>
) {}

invokeAction<MyService>("fooAction", 1, "foo")  // This is supposed to work ✅ 
invokeAction<MyService>("barAction", "bar")     // This is supposed to work ✅ 
invokeAction<MyService>("barAction", 1, "foo")  // This is NOT supposed to work ❌

invokeAction<MyOtherService>("otherAction", 1)  // This is supposed to work ✅ 
invokeAction<MyOtherService>("barAction", "bar) // This is NOT supposed to work ✅

With this, the action options are correctly chosen based on the service. But ...args includes the parameters of all actions available in TService. Can I somehow narrow this down without the need to type out the action twice like here:
function invokeActionWorkaround<
  TService extends BaseService,
  TAction extends Exclude<keyof TService, keyof BaseService> & string
>(
  action: TAction,
  ...args: Parameters<Extract<TService[TAction], (...args: any) => any>>
) {}

Here I must specify the action name twice (without IntelliSense), but the args are correctly determined for the action.

You have apparently already accepted an answer, but this approach is how I would suggest you approach this issue if you want to keep your code the same without currying; if that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining, but I'm not generally in the habit of trying to make other people lose points. How would you like to proceed here?

@jcalz your solution was what I had in mind initially. But it turns out, that the invoker solution actually keeps my code a little more clean, as I call multiple actions for the same service without having to specify the service every time.
Me personally, I understand your solution but it might help some people searching for this problem who want to use your solution. So, feel free to add an explanation :)

To add to the differences in approaches: The non-currying solution fails to identify the correct action args in IntelliSense. Its a minor problem, but seeing as I want this helper to be used by others it might be confusing.

You could use a factory function that returns an invoke function that uses methods from the provided type:
Playground
type MethodKeys<T extends object> = keyof {[K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? K : never]: any};

function invoker<TService extends BaseService>(){
  return function <K extends MethodKeys<TService>>(
  action: K,
  ...args: TService[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? Parameters<TService[K]> : never
) {}

}
const invokeAction = invoker<MyService>();
invokeAction("fooAction", 1, "foo")  // This is supposed to work ✅ 
invokeAction("barAction", "bar")     // This is supposed to work ✅ 
invokeAction("barAction", 1, "foo")  // This is NOT supposed to work ❌

const invokeAction2 = invoker<MyOtherService>();
invokeAction2("otherAction", 1)  // This is supposed to work ✅ 
invokeAction2("barAction", "bar") // This is NOT supposed to work ✅

